# angular2 listening for changes with Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm new to Firebase and I would like to listen for changes in the database.

This is what I have tried

```
constructor(
  private af:AngularFire,
 ){

  this.af.database().ref('registered').on('value', function(snapshot) { //syntax error
    console.log("changed");
  });

  }
```

How do I listen for changes with Firebase and angular2?

I have also tried setting up on the OnInit

```
OnInit(){
    this.af.database().ref('registered').on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log("changed");
     });

}
```

and returns an error `this.af.database is not a function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Angularfire with Firebase SDK syntaxes.

With AngularFire you have to use something like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

items: Observable<any[]>;
constructor(af: AngularFire) {
  this.items = af.list('/registered');
}
```

If you want to use only Firebase sdk you can do this (presuming you have the firebase file on your project):

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
constructor(){}

OnInit(){
  firebase.database().ref('registered').on('value', snapshot => {
    console.log('changed');
  })
}
```

### EDIT

As said in comment, one can subscribe to a observable in order to execute another function inside of it. This function will be executed until the observable is unsubscribed.

Comment: Using the first example can i listen for changes and call another function i.e console.log() like you have put in the second example

Comment: I have tried  af.database().ref('registered').on('value', snapshot => {
      console.log('changed') but am getting an error Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

Comment: Yes you can, you just need to subscribe to it since it's a promise, and then every time the value changes it'll call the function inside the subscribe.

Comment: Does it says where the error is? i think it's beacuse you're using the second code with AngularFire instead of firebase itself.